# Bandwidth from Linux to Linux (8Gbps) greater than from Linux to Windows(600Mbps)

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu-18.04, 10gbit

On the one hand I am using a Nvidia Jetson Nano together with an Auvidea Carrier Board JNX30B and a 10Gbps network card (ASUS XG-C100C).
On the other hand I am using a desktop computer equipped with Intel X550 network card. Both network cards are connected with a standardized ether-net cable of category CAT 7 and are able to transfer data with 10Gbps.
Ubuntu 18.04 is running on the Jetson Nano and Windows 10 Home is running on my desktop computer. Additionally, I have the possibility to run Ubuntu 18.04 via an external SSD drive on my desktop computer.
I am using iPerf3 for measuring the bandwidth.

**What works so far:**
Once I run Ubuntu 18.04 via the external SSD drive on my desktop computer connected to Jetson Nano I achieve at least 8Gbps. During the measurement I am using Jetson Nano as Sever and the desktop computer as Client:
[Linux to Linux measured by Iperf3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVSV8.png)

**Now to my problem:**
When I run Windows 10 Home on my desktop computer using the same Hardware as above I just achieve 660Mbps:
[Linux to Windows measured by Iperf3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPkdZ.png)

**What I've tried so far but didn't solve the problem:**

First, I have proofed the Intel drivers on my desktop computer by the driver support assistant. This assistant came to the result that all drivers are up to date.

Second, I checked the settings of both network cards and made sure that the auto negotiation and speed (10Gbps) is set up.

[Settings of Asus 10Gbits network card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzJ3I.png)

[Settings of IntelX550 network card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loO2h.png)

Third, I tried to resize the TCP Window size on my windows home system to 85,3kB as described here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/description-tcp-features

Does anybody of you had the same issue or know why Windows reduces the bandwidth anyway?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Cheers

Christoph

Comment: Can you try iperf3 in parallel mode, or even iperf v2 in multi-thread mode?

Comment: In parallel mode (iperf3 -c 192.168.2.2 -R -P5) I just achieve a bandwidth of 1.62Gbits/sec. That is more but still far away from my results on Ubuntu. On the other hand, using iperf v2 I achieve about 820Mbits/sec. Multithreading in iperf v2 achieves the same result as multithreading in iperf3.